# error: expected ‘}’ before ‘else’?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I get these errors when I compile my code.

```
experiment.cpp: In function ‘void convert(char*)’:
experiment.cpp:47:5: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘else’
experiment.cpp:47:5: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘else’
experiment.cpp: At global scope:
experiment.cpp:53:3: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
```

But I do not understand why. I checked all the bracing many times.

```
void convert(char *infix)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
    {
       if(isalpha(infix[i]))
          printf("%c",infix[i]);
       else if(ispunct(infix[i]))
       {
           if(!isempty())
               push(infix[i]);
           else
           {
               if(check(infix[i]));
                  push(infix[i]);
               else
               {
                  printf("%c",pop());
                  push(infix[i]);
               }
           }
       }    
    }
}
```

Comment: note: ugly code. learn to use `&&` and `||`. eliminate duplication.

Comment: Remove ; in the line 46

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in:

```
               if(check(infix[i]));
```

Remove the trailing `;`

```
               if(check(infix[i]))
```

Answer (score 3):

`if(check(infix[i]));`: remove the `;` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is like writing:

```
if(check(infix[i])) { }  //if(something); == if(something) { }
push(infix[i]);
else                     //See why there's a problem?
```

It's a good practice to have `{` even if you have only one line under the statement. 
Doing that might help you to reveal possible problems, like this `;` you have there.

Another note, use `&&` for clarity instead of nested `if`s..